# GoogleApiClient: "Result has already been consumed" in multi-thread Android app

Tags: android, multithreading, google-play-services, google-signin

what's the best approach to handle

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Result has already been consumed.
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzly.await(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmo.await(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmo.get(Unknown Source)
```

which happens when using two different GoogleApiClients from different threads?

I have a MainActivity, that onStart() builds a new instance of GoogleApiClient, and then calls

```
OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = 
    GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(googleApiClient);
opr.setResultCallback(myCallback);
```

At the same time, the activity starts an IntentService (to refresh GCM token) that also builds a new GoogleApiClient instance, and calls

```
OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = 
    GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(googleApiClient);
opr.await(); // Blocks
return opr.get();
```

The exception occurs on `opr.get()` call. Seems that GoogleApiClient shares its resources somewhere, and creating a new instance of it doesn't relieve me from managing some cross-thread state.

What's your approach of using GoogleApiClient when you need it twice?

Keeping a static holder of ApiClient?
Keeping a shared atomic reference like "we're connecting right now please hold"?
Having some wrapper around GoogleApiClient?

**UPDATE**

MainActivity needs GoogleApiClient for making sure user is signed in, and to show a prompt if not.

IntentService actually needs only GoogleSignInAccount, for OAuth token. But to make sure the token still fresh, it obtains a fresh account using GoogleApiClient. So maybe storing the GoogleSignInAccount in some shared store would help as well. But how do I know whether it still fresh then?

Comment: Both GoogleApiClient-s are almost identical, the difference is that Activity have it `enableAutoManage(this, this)`, while IntentService calls connect()/disconnect() itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `opr.await()` already consumes resource and returns it. Should be

```
OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = 
    GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(googleApiClient);
return opr.await(); // Blocks
```